# Limit counsel-locate to certain file type and directory

Tags: ivy, counsel

CentOS 7, Emacs 27.2, Ivy, Swiper, Counsel package.

In `Temp` folder I have different files. I want to find using `counsel-locate` all text files only in this folder and **all subfolders**.

I try this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see I use command `M-x counsel-locate .txt` but `counsel` finds ALL text files in whole HDD. But I need to find all text files ONLY in the folder `Temp`.

Is this possible with the `counsel` package?

P.S.

```
(defun adl/counsel-locate-in-the-current-folder-and-subfolders ()
  (interactive)
  (counsel-locate (concat (file-truename default-directory) " ")))
```

Work only for current folder. But I need to find also in all subfolders.
Here screenshots
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try ``M-x counsel-locate $PWD/*.txt``. This command will probably find all txt files in the current folder and its subfolders.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196744/unix-locate-command-for-present-working-directory#6196798

Comment: @adl $PWD/*.txt - not work this approach. Result is Nothing found

Comment: An alternate option is `counsel-fd-file-jump` from `counsel-fd` which lists all files under the current directory. You can select `.txt` files easily using `ivy`.

Comment: @a_subscriber The reason the subfolders are not being found is most likely because `locate` hasn't indexed them, so I don't think it's `counsel-locate`'s fault. See my updated answer, as well as `man locate` and `man updatedb`.

Comment: @Basil yes, you was right. ONLY AFTER one day the method "adl/counsel-locate-in-the-current-folder-and-subfolders" success show text files in current folder and all subfolders.

Answer (score 2):

`counsel-locate` essentially just calls the system `locate` command (see [`man 1 locate`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locate.1.html)).

You can control which executable is called by customising the user option `locate-command` from the built-in package `locate.el`.

You can further control the exact command that `counsel-locate` issues by customising the user option `counsel-locate-cmd`.

On GNU/Linux, the default command issued by `counsel-locate` is:

```
locate -i --regex REGEXP
```

where `REGEXP` is the user input interpreted as a [regular expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html).

So, to find any `.txt` files under any directory called `Temp`, you need an input like `Temp \.txt\'` or `Temp.*\.txt\'` (note that the literal full stop `.` has to be escaped, that `\'` anchors the file extension at the end of the file name, and that Ivy translates the first pattern into something equivalent to the second pattern by default).

To find any `.txt` files under a specific directory called `Temp`, you need an input like

```
\`/home/alexeij/Temp \.txt\'
```

or

```
\`/home/alexeij/Temp.*\.txt\'
```

Where the

```
\`
```

anchors the search at the start of the file name.

Finally, to start every `counsel-locate` search in the current directory, you can write a custom command like the following based on [adl's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/66212/15748):

```el
(defun my-counsel-locate-here ()
  "Start `counsel-locate' anchored at `default-directory'."
  (interactive)
  (counsel-locate (rx bos (literal (file-truename default-directory)) ?\s)))
```

Then you can issue e.g. `M-x my-counsel-locate-here RET \.txt\'` to find all `.txt` files under the current directory.

A more direct (but sometimes slower) way of achieving the same thing is `M-x counsel-file-jump RET \.txt\'`.

For a fuzzy search analogue, there's also e.g. `M-x counsel-fzf RET .txt`.

---

**Update**

> P.S. [`adl/counsel-locate-in-the-current-folder-and-subfolders`] work only for current folder. But I need to find also in all subfolders.

The `locate` command usually depends on indexing your filesystem in order to answer queries efficiently.  Are you sure the subfolders in question have been indexed already?  Usually `locate` updates its database daily in the background, but you can force it via [`updatedb`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/updatedb.1.html).

In any case I think `adl/counsel-locate-in-the-current-folder-and-subfolders` is working fine (except for the fact that it doesn't quote and anchor regular expressions properly, see the `my-counsel-locate-here` example), so the problem is most likely a pilot error/misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to start `counsel-locate` already with the current directory in it and an space. Then you could type whatever you want to search there.

```
(defun adl/counsel-locate-in-the-current-folder-and-subfolders ()
  (interactive)
  (counsel-locate (concat (file-truename default-directory) " ")))
```

Comment: Try your custom function. Locate: /home/alexeij/Temp/*.txt, but result is "Nothing found"

Comment: You have to use an space instead of the * ``/home/alexeij/Temp/ .txt`` . The function already adds the space after the current directory name.

Comment: Not work. I was updated my post

Comment: @a_subscriber I've confirmed that it works, so it must be a case of pilot error.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this approach:

```el
(defun my-insert-default-directory ()
  "Insert `default-directory' at point."
  (interactive)
  (insert (file-truename default-directory)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-d") #'my-insert-default-directory) ;; custom function
```

[image]

During `M-x counsel-locate`, if I press `C-c C-d` I get the following result:

[image]

I do not need the current directory every time. So when I need it I use `C-c C-d`.

Comment: Since the input to `counsel-locate` is interpreted as a regexp by default, I recommend passing the result of `file-truename` through [`regexp-quote`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Functions.html) before inserting it.